# Zoom and crop a pdf document using PyMuPDF fitz and saving as pdf

Tags: python, pdf, lambda, pymupdf

I am trying to crop a pdf within and lambda and save the file. Ideally I just want to zoom in as otherwise the OCR package does not recognize some of the fonts. The rectangle I am using just seems to shift the margins versus actually cropping or zooming in.

Thanks!

```
import os
import json
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import fitz, sys
from io import BytesIO


OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ["OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME"]
OUTPUT_S3_PREFIX = os.environ["OUTPUT_S3_PREFIX"]
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = os.environ["SNS_TOPIC_ARN"]
SNS_ROLE_ARN = os.environ["SNS_ROLE_ARN"]


def lambda_handler(event, context):

   
    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        filename = unquote_plus(str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"]))
        
        doc = fitz.open()
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        obj = s3.Object(bucketname, filename)
        fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        pdf=fitz.open("pdf", stream=BytesIO(fs))
 
        
        
        rect=fitz.Rect(50, 50, 545, 792)
 
        page = pdf[0]
        page1 = doc.new_page(width = rect.width,  # new page with ...
                      height = rect.height)
        page1.show_pdf_page(rect, pdf, 0)  
        
        new_bytes = doc.write()
        bucketname1='modified'
        s3.Bucket(bucketname1).put_object(Key=filename, Body=new_bytes)
```

Comment: My specific example is a table and I can crop it locally and run it through OCR and get the correct table rows when using "import pdfCropMargins"

Comment: What would you suggest to use as an alternative, especially given I am running this in a lambda.  The biggest issue is the line separation for a table for only a couple of the lines. Otherwise mostly works great.

Comment: Do you know how I would "scale up" with fitz?